# Geometry 1 - Finding the value of AC

Tags: geometry

[image]

If I want to find the value of $x$ which is $AC$, these are the steps for my attempt:

$$\frac{AC}{CE} = \frac{AB}{AD}$$

$$\frac{x}{1.3} = \frac{1.5}{2.4}$$

$$2.4x = 1.5 \cdot 1.3$$

$$x = 0.81$$

That is the incorrect answer. I am so frustrated, I don't know where I am going wrong?!?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use similar triangles.  The sides you need are AC and AE, AB and AD.  You see triangle ABC and triangle ADE are similar triangles.  So ratios of corresponding sides are equal.

$$ \frac{AC}{AE} = \frac{AB}{AD}$$

From this substitute in what you know.

$$ \frac{x}{x+1.3} = \frac{1.5}{2.4} $$

It is now a matter of solving the resulting equation for x.

Comment: Best explanation I have ever received. I hope you write a book someday. + Bookmarked your youtube channel.

Comment: Thanks.  I appreciate the compliment.